# What are some kavachas you use?

Tags: kavacha

There are so many Kavachas available. I am interested in finding out which ones you use?
If you use multiple ones depending on the scenario, I would love to know the details too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rahu Kavacham. Since the current Mahadasha that is running is Rahu for me. I also use the Kavacha for the relevant Grahas when the relevant Praana Dasha comes in, on average every 2-3 days.

Since the Kavachas are slightly like Mantras and utilize (pseudo) nyaasas, it's best to not do many and keep the connection to as few as possible (preferably one). So, that's all that I use, 9 in total. Along with Aaditya Kavacha from Skanda Purana which I use daily.

> There are so many Kavachas available.

If you want to find which one to use, yourself, then look at the Phala Shruti that is most suited to your wants and just pick one with a Deva you feel more connected towards. That's pretty much all there is.

Comment: thank you , thats great suggestion.